# How to cast an int's address of two variable to char pointer in C?

Tags: c

I have the following code, but I'm getting incorrect output.
Can anybody tell me why output is `10 B` only and why I'm not getting `A` in output??

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int *p;
    char c,d;
    int i;

    clrscr();
    p=&i;
    *p=10;
    (char *)p=&c;
    *p=65;
    (char *)p=&d;
    *p=66;
    printf("%d%c%c",i,c,d);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: is `getch()` to wait for user input before Windows closes the Command Prompt?

Comment: This is a platform-specific question, so should provide that info (OS, compiler, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Your program invokes undefined behavior, so there's no correct or incorrect.  Specifically:

```
*p = 65;
```

writes an integer into memory with only room for a `char`.  C99 §6.5.3.2/4 (Address and indirection operations) states:

> If the operand has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’. If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is undeﬁned.84)

`p` has type pointer to `int`, so `*p` has type `int`.  However, `p` is not a the address of a valid `int` object.

Also, I believe the cast on the left side of the assignment is illegal (GCC definitely thinks so).

I believe what's happening is that it's laid out (increasing addressess) like:

```
|i|i|i|i|d|c|p|p|p|p|
```

This represents the bytes each occupies.  I'll walk through what I think is happening:

```
p = &i;

|i|i|i|i|d|c|00|00|00|00|
```

For simplicity, I assume the address of `i` is 0.

```
*p=10;

|10|0|0|0|d|c|00|00|00|00|

p=&c;

|10|0|0|0|d|c|05|00|00|00|

*p=65;

|i|i|i|i|d|65|00|00|00|00|
```

Note that modifying `*p` overwrites `p`.

```
p=&d;

|10|0|0|0|d|65|04|00|00|00|

*p=66;

|10|0|0|0|66|00|00|00|00|00|
```

So storing to `d` overwrites `c` with NULL.  The above applies if your machine is little-endian, has 4-byte ints, and the stack grows upwards (towards lower addresses).  The analysis is different if you have 2-byte ints, but the main conclusion still applies.

Returning `void` is also illegal, but that's unrelated.

Comment: I don't think that the assignment of the `int`'s here can be the problem. They are all in the guaranteed range of `char`, no? As long as the value of such an assignment fits there is no undefined behavior. BTW, things as `'a'` or `'\n'` are `int`, too.

Comment: @Jens, no, the range doesn't matter.  Storing an int (i.e. having an int on the left side of `=`) is still going to write `sizeof(int)` bytes.  I am aware that character constants like `'a'` are ints.

Answer (score 3):

The statement `(char *)p=&c;` doesn't magically turn `p` into a `char *` from that point on. In the next line, `*p=65;`, you're still putting an `int` into that location.

Ditto for `(char *)p=&d; *p=66;`. Now because you're inserting what's almost certainly two bytes into the single byte `d`, you're probably overwriting `c` with 0.

You may find that changing `*p = 66` to `*((char*)p) = 66` will give you what you want, the insertion of a single byte.

And, please, upgrade to gcc if possible. It costs exactly the same as Turbo C and is better in just about *every* way.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use

```
p = (int *) &c;
```

but when you do

```
*p = 65
```

then the compiled program will put 65, as a 4-byte value (assuming your int is 4 byte) into the memory where `c` is residing.  It will trash 3 more bytes...  because `c` is only 1 byte, and you are putting 4 bytes of data into it...  and I wonder whether some platform will complain as `c` is a char, and may not be at an int boundary...

You probably want to use

```
char *pChar = &c;
*pChar = 65;
```

If you want to experiment with putting a byte 65 into the integer `i`, you can use

```
pChar = (char *) &i;
*pChar = 65;
```

The `(char *)` is called casting -- making it a pointer to character.

Answer (score 0):

I could not compile your program, it does not conform to ANSI standard. Here is fixed version and it prints "10AB":

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

int *p;
char *cp;
char c,d;
int i;
p=&i;
*p=10;
cp=&c;
*cp=65;
cp=&d;
*cp=66;
printf("%d%c%c\n",i,c,d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that the whole thing is a hack. Don't do that. There is no reason to cast `int` or `char` back and forth like that. You can only expect trouble from the way you write your code.

Some hints:

- the correct include file for standard
  C is `stdio.h`
- in C the expression `(char*)p` is not
  an lvalue, meaning that you can't
  assign to it. (this has good reasons)
- Even if you would succeed to assign
  the address of a `char` to an `int`
  pointer this would generally a bad
  idea. Not only because you will
  eventually override memory that is
  not "yours" but also because of
  alignment problems. The best that can
  happen to you in such a case is a
  `bus error`, to tell you early that
  you are on the wrong track
- the return type of `main` is `int`

Answer (score -1):

You are using the casting operator in wrong way. You an assiging an char * to int *. So you should cast that char * to allow the conversion. The correct code is as below:

```
int *p; char c,d; int i; 
p=&i; 
*p=10; 
p=(int *)&c; 
*p=65; 
p=(int *)&d; 
*p=66; 
printf("%d%c%c",i,c,d);
```

Comment: This code still invokes undefined behavior by storing an `int` where only a `char` will fit.